# Crypto update not working when decyphering

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

When creating a cipher this works

```
const key = Buffer.alloc(24,process.env.KEY, "base64");

let iv = Buffer.alloc(0);

let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3', key, iv);
let newKey = cipher.update(newApiKey,'utf-8', 'hex');
newKey += cipher.final('hex');
```

but when trying to decrypt this I get an undefined string as response

```
let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('des-ede3', key, iv);
let decrypted = decipher.update(newKey, 'hex', 'utf-8');
decrypted += decipher.final('utf-8');
console.log(decrypted);
```

Comment: Why are you passing an empty iv buffer?

Comment: I'm not sure how the iv really works tbh. While reading docs and other implementations most of them passed an empty buffer, so I chose to do the same.

Comment: It works for me.